# Easy valid way of unit testing C++ code you can't work out on paper

Tags: c++, unit-testing

I am trying to test some C++ code, using Visual Studio 2015's built in unit test framework. I have written some code which is testing an hourly, daily & weekly model, to see which one most reliably fits a set of real life data, by calculating the Coefficient of Determination (R^2).

The real life data needs to be "Read" off of a graph, I have a tested and validated routine which does this.

I know that I am expecting the weekly model to fit perfectly, and the other two won't. To dot his on paper would require ~300 equation calcs to get the values I am working with and then work out the R^2 value. I would rather not do that...

How can I test this code? I am new to Unit Testing as a concept and am still understanding the paradigms used when testing functions.

My Code:

Where History and Graph are Vectors of Vectors.

```
float calculateDeviation(int period) {
    int x1 = history.front()[0];
    int x2 = x1 + period;
    int i = 0, minimum, maximum, SSres = 0, SStot = 0, j=0, R2 =0;
    float  average = 0;
    int endTime = history.back()[0];
    while (x2 <= history.back()[0]) {
        average += averageGradient(x1, x2);
        x1 = x2;
        x2 += period;
    }

    x1 = history.front()[0];
    x2 = x1 + period;
    i++;
    while (j < i) {
        SSres += pow((graph[i][0]-((graph[i][2]*graph[i][0])+graph[i][3])), 2);
        SStot += pow(graph[i][0] - average, 2);
        x1 = x2;
        x2 =+ period;
        j++;
    }

    R2 = 1 - (SSres / SStot);
    return history.back()[0];
}
```

Comment: Without seeing the code that you're using, I'd suggest passing it mock datasets you know the answers to.

Comment: 1. where's your code? 2. what does "read" off a graph mean? 3. what does "testing an hour, daily, and weekly model" mean?

Comment: @Bleys Thanks! That's what I thought, but how do I get these Mock datasets?

Comment: It sounds like you are running a simulation, not unit testing.

Comment: I think you would just actually make some mock datasets yourself, I.E this part would require some 'writing on paper' working out manually some sets, one you KNOW should be weekly, one you know should be daily, and you know should be hourly etc.

Hard to avoid some manual calculation here in your unit testing

Comment: @WearyWanderer I am happy to do some Paper Calcs, but that would require me to produce values for every hour, over a 2 - 3 week period. I want to avoid spending that much time producing the data set?

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe Not quite sure what the difference is? This is only one function is a much larger group of routines.

Comment: Can't you make up some values that you know would be expected in a data set? That's what I meant, sorry if I was unclear. Usually when unit testing you will make some meaningful test data that you alreayd know what the outcome should be.


Say I wanted to unit test a function that counts the 'a' chars in a string. I would make a unit test passing "This is a bad string" and expect the outcome to be 2. In your case, it sounds more like it doesnt matter what the values are so you could make some random ones up, just so long as they are spread over a period you know evaluates to daily/weekly etc

Comment: @GeorgeEdwards We're not saying to use real data. We're saying to make a set of data points (in whatever format you're passing in - a graph in this case) that should produce that result. It should actually be easier with a graph, as you only have to generate a section of the points along that line.

Comment: Apologies if I am wrong but in terms of what you are testing it does not sound like the actual values need to be 'real'

Comment: @WearyWanderer I don't need real values, but it would ideally need to be generated by the functions that populate the Vectors, as they make up quite a bit of the functionality of that routine.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a practicing Test Engineer, and based on what you've provided, you should be able to write a basic unit test with the following:

1. Prepare your input data. This means your "period" variable, as well as sample graph data. As the author of your graphs and logic, you should be able to create a simple data set that other engineers can understand.
2. Prepare your response data. This means "the answer". No test is complete without a data-set to compare the results against.
3. In the Unit Test, simply pass in the proper input data, and validate the results against pre-verified values.

Remember to prepare several sets of input data, including boundaries (minimums, maximums, and values that should fail). This is often the breaking point, so be sure to run tests that require error handling. If you can think of a way to break your code, then you've successfully identified an area that needs some tweaking. And that, my friend, is the entire point. :)